# Calcular uma rota pelo Google Mapa e multiplicar a distancia por um valor em reais

Tags: div

Um colega postou esse código e reaproveitei ele no meu site mais gostaria de fazer uma multiplicação com a distancia entre os dois pontos, por exemplo a distancia deu 1000 km quero multiplicar essa distancia por 2 = R$ 2000,00...
algum pode me ajudar.

```
<script>
function CalculaDistancia() {
        $('#litResultado').html('Aguarde...');
        //Instanciar o DistanceMatrixService
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        //executar o DistanceMatrixService
        service.getDistanceMatrix(
          {
              //Origem
              origins: [$("#txtOrigem").val()],
              //Destino
              destinations: [$("#txtDestino").val()],
              //Modo (DRIVING | WALKING | BICYCLING)
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
              //Sistema de medida (METRIC | IMPERIAL)
              unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
              //Vai chamar o callback
          }, callback);
    }
    //Tratar o retorno do DistanceMatrixService
    function callback(response, status) {
        //Verificar o Status
        if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK)
            //Se o status não for "OK"
            $('#litResultado').html(status);
        else {
            //Se o status for OK
            //Endereço de origem = response.originAddresses
            //Endereço de destino = response.destinationAddresses
            //Distância = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text
            //Duração = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text
            var x = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
            $('#litResultado').html("<strong>Origem</strong>: "+ response.originAddresses +
            "<br /><strong>Destino:</strong> "+ response.destinationAddresses +
            "<br /><strong>Distância</strong>: "+ response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text +
            " <br /><strong>Duração</strong>: "+ response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text
            );
            //Atualizar o mapa
            $("#map").attr("src", "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + 
            response.originAddresses + "&daddr=" + response.destinationAddresses +  
            "&output=embed");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: opa muito bom nao conseguia fazer isso deixar identado.

Comment: como vc faz isso